# In a loop function, find all classes after the page is updated through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have added function in `jQuery` which runs every 5 seconds. This function:

1. Collects current records in a array `currentRecords`
2. Makes an `AJAX` call and gets the new records in an array `newRecords`
3. If the `newRecords` list contains a new record, this is added to the page.

The above logic is working right:

HTML:

```
<div class="pending-calls">
   <div class="call-record" id="id1">Record 1</div>
   <div class="call-record" id="id2">Record 2</div>
   <div class="call-record" id="id3">Record 3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function worker() {
    
    //Get current records
    var currentRecords = [];
    $('.call-record').each(function () {
        currentRecords.push($(this).prop('id'););
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '#',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {              
            //Save records to an array and find the new record. If you find a new one, prepend it 'newRow' to the page.
            $('.pending-calls').prepend(newRow);
            //e.g <div class="call-record" id="id4">Record 4</div>
        },
        complete: function () {             
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```

However, when a new record is found and it is added to the page, on the next loop the `$('.call-record')..` doesn't catch it and as a result this new record `<div class="call-record" id="id4">Record 4</div>` is added endlessly in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your initial selector doesn't capture new elements added later. To solve this, use the `.on()` method to detect and add newly inserted call-record elements to `currentRecords`. This is the modified `js`.

```
(function worker() {
    
    //Get current records
    var currentRecords = [];
    $('.call-record').each(function () {
        currentRecords.push($(this).prop('id'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '#',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {              
            //Save records to an array and find the new record. If you find a new one, prepend it 'newRow' to the page.
            $('.pending-calls').prepend(newRow);
            //e.g <div class="call-record" id="id4">Record 4</div>
        },
        complete: function () {             
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });

    //Bind a function to the `.pending-calls` element that will execute whenever a new `.call-record` element is added to the page.
    $('.pending-calls').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.call-record', function () {
        //Add the new element to the `currentRecords` array.
        currentRecords.push($(this).prop('id'));
    });
})();
```

Hope this works for you.

**PS:** Please Note that Using `DOMNodeInserted` may lead to performance problems when there are frequent additions of numerous elements to the `DOM`. Event handling might be excessive if real-time response to `DOM` changes isn't necessary

Answer (score 1):

I found a walk around to my problem. I placed the array `currentRecords` outside of the function, so when the page is loaded it is filled once with the current records. After the `ajax` call, if I found a new record I added to the list.

```
//Get current records
var currentRecords = [];
$('.call-record').each(function () {
    currentRecords.push($(this).prop('id'););
});

(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '#',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {              
            //Save records to an array and find the new record. If you find a new one, prepend 'newRow' to the page.
            if(newRowIsFound){
                //add the id in the array
                currentRecords.push(newRow.id);
           
                //Add it to the page e.g <div class="call-record" id="id4">Record 4</div>
                $('.pending-calls').prepend(newRow);
            }
        },
        complete: function () {             
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```